# Powershell: Replace in cyrillic string

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I cannot replace successfully cyrillic string.

My file is encoded by UTF-8 with BOM/

Code of powershell script:

```
$Title = "название видео"
$Title = $Title.Replace("название", "")
Write-Host $Title
cmd /c pause
```

Result:

[image: Resulting string]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution:

```
   function ConvertTo-Encoding ([string]$From, [string]$To){
        Begin{
            $encFrom = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding($from)
            $encTo = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding($to)
        }
        Process{
            $bytes = $encTo.GetBytes($_)
            $bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Convert($encFrom, $encTo, $bytes)
            $encTo.GetString($bytes)
        }
    }

    [System.Text.Encoding]::Default.Codepage

    $Title = "название видео" | ConvertTo-Encoding "UTF-8" "windows-1251"
    Write-Host $Title
    $Title = $Title.Replace(("название" | ConvertTo-Encoding "UTF-8" "windows-1251"), "")
    Write-Host $Title
    cmd /c pause
```

Comment: Bat it needs change: $Text=($_).ToString();$bytes=$encTo.GetBytes($Text) because, single boolean variables even though they are strings - throw an error.

Answer (score 3):

I can't reproduce your problem. Nevertheless, let me guess that output from `[System.Console]::OutputEncoding.Codepage` is `1251`. You could change console encoding to `Unicode (UTF-8)` (codepage `65001`) on the fly; try to modify your script as follows:

```
### debug ### [System.Console]::OutputEncoding
[System.Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
### debug ### [System.Console]::OutputEncoding
$Title = "название видео"
$Title = $Title.Replace("название", "")
Write-Host $Title
pause
```

Or change console encoding to `Unicode` (codepage `1200`) using

```
[System.Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode
```

Answer (score 1):

Change file encoding to windows1251 (with visual code, notepad++, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Change the font from raster to some of the true type fonts

Comment: Click with right button at the top of the consile window, Properties > Font